# Why C++ compiler chooses wrong function (templates)

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang, overload-resolution

I did some tests and encountered this strange behavior.

```
struct A{};

struct B : A{};

#include <iostream>

template<class T>
void fn2(T const &){
}

void fn2(A const &){
    std::cout << "Here\n";
}

template<class T>
void fn1(){
    T a;

    fn2(a);
}

int main(){
    fn1<B>();
}
```

I did clean up the code. When run, I expect it prints "here". However it call templated version of `fn2()`.

I did test in godbolt as well. There I rewrited the function `fn1()` and `fn2()`, so they return `int`. At that point, compiler did the right thing.

Here is how I compile:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic bug.cc  -lstdc++
$ ./a.out 
$ clang -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic bug.cc  -lstdc++
$ ./a.out 
$
```

Comment: What do you mean? The program never prints "Here", not with `void`, nor with `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The template version is selected because it's an exact match (with `T` deduced as `B`). For the non-template version to be called, the implicit version from `B` to `A` is required; then the template version wins in overload resolution.

You can apply [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) with `std::enable_if` and `std::is_base_of` to eliminate the template version from the overload set when `T` is deduced as `A` or its derived classes.

```
template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of_v<A, T>> fn2(T const &){
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate more about it, because I can change few changes, not related to what did you said and it will call correct version.

Comment: @Nick You mean you want workaround to make the non-template one to be called?